# Aurelia dependencies issue when using feathers-authentication-client

Tags: aurelia, feathersjs

I add a npm package to my aurelia.json file

```
{
    "name": "feathers-authentication-client",
    "path": "../node_modules/feathers-authentication-client/lib",
    "main": "index"
}
```

then I import it

`import * as auth from 'feathers-authentication-client';`

but I keep getting this error:

`{ Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\path\to\project-folder\src\feathers-errors.js' ...`

if I add this package to aurelia.json too then I get the same error but for a dependency of `feathers-errors` etc.. etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

thanks to @AshleyGrant that helped with this. Here's the solution:

- make sure you have this under `dependencies` in the `aurelia.json` file

  ```
  {
    "name": "feathers-client",
    "path": "../node_modules/feathers-client/dist",
    "main": "feathers"
  },
  {
    "name": "feathers-authentication-client",
    "main": "lib/index",
    "path": "../node_modules/feathers-authentication-client",
    "resources": []
  },
  "feathers-errors",
  "ms",
  {
    "name": "debug",
    "main": "browser",
    "path": "../node_modules/debug"
  },
  {
    "name": "jwt-decode",
    "main": "index",
    "path": "../node_modules/jwt-decode/lib",
    "resources": ["base64_url_decode.js", "atob.js"]
  }
  ```

Comment: I'm working with our CLI team to see if this can be done automatically with `au install`